# How to read notifications using React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I have a use case where I want to be able to read notifications that I receive on my phone using React native. The notifications are not of the specific app but of all the other applications on the phone.
The idea is to log all these incoming notifications.

Example:
Suppose if I get notifications from Yahoo!, Facebook, Instagram, Medium, System notifications etc... my React Native app should be able to read and log them all.